# Mongoose document update- selected objects in array - with $in operator

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My schema is as below.

Customer: {

```
orders: [{
     ...
    status: 'Pending'
        ...
}]
```

}

I have a list of order ids whose which are delivered to the customer. So I need to change the Status to closed. This is my simple requirement. I have my below code, which updates the status 'closed' only for the first order id in the OrderIdList.

orderIdList = ["54899c0cbdde6b281e9aaa22","54899c28bdde6b281e9aaa23","54899c2abdde6b281e9aaa24","54899c2cbdde6b281e9aaa25"]

```
Customer.update({
    'orders._id': {
        $in: orderIdList
    }
}, {
    '$set': {
        'orders.$.status': 'Closed'
    }
}, {
    multi: true,
    upsert: true
}, function(err, rows) {
    console.log("error");
    console.log(err);
    console.log("rows updated");
    console.log(rows);
});
```

Only one row is updated. for the orderId "54899c0cbdde6b281e9aaa22"

Why is it not updating for all the order Ids. Please suggest me the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *which updates the status 'closed' only for the first order id in the
>   OrderIdList.*

Yes, that is how the positional operator([$](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)) works. It updates only the first item in an array that has matched the condition in the query.

From the docs,

> the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the **first** element
>   that matches the query document.

`multi: true` is applicable for parent documents and not for embedded documents. If this parameter is set to true, all the documents that have an order matching the required Id, will be updated. But the positional operator will update only the first sub document that matched the query in all these documents.

To update all the matching orders for all the matching document, currently it is not possible in a single mongo update query. You need to perform the logic in the application code.

One way of doing it in the application code:

- Match all the customer documents which contain an order that we are
  looking for.
- For each customer document identify the orders that we need to
  update.
- Modify the order.
- Perform an update based on the Customer document `_id`.

Sample Code:

```
var orderIdList = ['54899c0cbdde6b281e9aaa22'];
Customer.find({"orders._id":{$in:orderIdList }},function(err,resp){
resp.forEach(function(doc){
var orders = doc.orders;
orders.forEach(function(order){
if(orderIdList.indexOf(order._id.toString()) != -1){
order.status = 'closed';
Customer.update({"_id":doc._id},{$set:{"orders":orders}},function(err,aff,raw){
console.log("Updated: "+aff);
});}})})})
```